# auto timeoutDuration don't work on synchronized carousels

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

i get two synchronized caroufredsel instances

```
    jQuery("#sliderHome").carouFredSel({
        items: 1,
        width: 1280,
        height: 510,
        prev: {
            button: jQuery('.paginate .prev')
        },
        next: {
            button: jQuery('.paginate .next')
        },
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            fx: "fade",
            duration: 500,
            pauseOnHover: false
        },
        auto: {
            timeoutDuration: 8000
        }
    });

    jQuery('.push.comingsoon ul').carouFredSel({
        items: 1,
        width: 297,
        height: 297,
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            fx: "fade",
            duration: 500,
            pauseOnHover: false
        },
        prev: {
            button: jQuery('.paginate .prev')
        },
        next: {
            button: jQuery('.paginate .next')
        },
        synchronise: '#sliderHome'

    });
```

the problem is, i can't affect the timeoutDuration of the auto parameter, nor the scroll duration. If i set the duration for both instances, the synchronise thing goes away (when they are synchronized, the carousels both slide when i click on .prev or .next)

Does anybody is getting a similar issue with caroufredsel ?

Comment: PLease create a jsfiddle or share a link so I can try to help please.

Answer (score 0):

I ended removing the synchronised option & making similar carousels (equal timeoutDuration), and binding prev/next to the same buttons, works fine.